# Dynamically refresh pods on secrets update on kubernetes while using helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I am creating deployment,service manifest files using helm charts, also secrets by helm but separately not with deployments and service.
secretes are being loaded as env variables on pod level.

we are looking  to refresh or restart PODs when we update secrets with new content.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes does not itself support this feature at the moment and there is feature in the works (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368).

You can use custom solution available to achieve the same and one of the popular ones include [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader).